# setTimeout not pausing iterations in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to iterate through a list of orders, pausing each one for 3 seconds. Then once complete, start again in a loop.

In the snippet below, if the loop is enabled it seems to be starting the loop again before the first loop has completed.

Also the 3 second pause between each call to display_notification is not working.

```
start: function() { 
    $.each(this.orders, function(index, order) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log ('show notification');
            recentlyApp.display_notification(order);
        }, index * 3000);
    });
    if (this.settings.loop) {
        this.start();
    }
},
display_notification: function(order) {
    console.log(order);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is an asynchronous, non-blocking method. This means you're actually iterating through each loop in microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you're already using jQuery, you can create a plugin to loop through an array in an interval.

Example:

```js
// timer function that loops through an array with in a given interval
$.timer = function (list, callback, time/*, onFinish, index*/) {
  var onFinish = arguments.length > 3 ? arguments[3] : void 0,
      index = arguments.length > 4 ? arguments[4] : 0;
  
  if (index < list.length) {
    list.__timed = setTimeout(function() {
      callback.call(this, index, list[index]);
      $.timer(list, callback, time, onFinish, ++index);
    }, time);
  }
  else if (onFinish){
    onFinish.call(this);
  }

  return {
    cancel: function() {
      if (list.__timed !== void 0) {
        clearTimeout(list.__timed);
        delete list.__timed;
      }
    }
  };
}

// usage
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var timer = $.timer(arr, function (index, item) {
  document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>' + item + '</div>');
}, 3000, function() {
  document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>Finished</div>');
});

// cancelling the loop
$('button').click(function(e) {
  timer.cancel();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>Cancel timer</button>
```

So, in your scenario, it would be something like this:

```
start: function() { 
  $.timer(this.orders, function(index, order) {
    console.log('show notification');
    recentlyApp.display_notification(order);
  }, 3000, this.settings.loop ? this.start : void 0);
},
display_notification: function(order) {
  console.log(order);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now, the `$.timer` is returning an object with the `cancel` method, so you can cancel the loop at anytime by calling `.cancel();`.

I've created a `__timed` property into the array to always get the last `setTimeout` executed, so when you call the `cancel` method, it calls the `clearTimeout` for what it was going to call next.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the timer from within another function, for example if a close button is clicked to end the cycle?

Comment: @AsaCarter you must change the plugin code in a way it can be cancelable. Let me try to do it, and I'll update the answer if I figure out how to.

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to get the index outside of the timer function? I need to set a different time on the first element the first time it is run.

Comment: It would also be good to pause the notifications on mouse hover and resume. I'm having a go at creating pause and resume methods.

Comment: I've fixed the the first element timing issue by moving it outside of the timeout. I've added pause and resume. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpNbxZ
Is there anything you would change?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `this.start()` as soon as you've finished the loop that *sets up* the timeout functions.

Either track the last value of `index` and use it to set a timeout on the call to `start()` or put the call to `start()` in the last timed out function you set going in the loop.